# sql (beginner) - use value calculated from above cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**EDIT**

*the values in the table can be negative numbers (sorry for the oversight when asking the question)*

Having exhausted all search efforts, I am very stuck with the following:

I would like to calculate a running total based on the initial value. For instance:

My table would look like:

```
Year  Percent   Constant
====  =====     ========

2000  1.40      100
2001  -1.08     100
2002  1.30      100
```

And the desired results would be:

```
Year  Percent   Constant  RunningTotal
====  ======    ========  ============

2000  1.40      100       140
2001  -1.08     100       128.8
2002  1.30      100       167.44
```

Taking the calculated value of 1.40*100 and multiplying it with percent of the next line, 1.08 and so on.

I am using Sql Server 2012. I've looked into using a common table expression, but can't seem to get the correct syntax sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this task using a recursive CTE

```
;WITH values_cte AS (
SELECT [Year]
      ,[Percent]
      ,[Constant]        
      ,CASE WHEN [v].[Percent] < 0 THEN
            [v].[Constant] - (([v].[Percent] + 1) * [v].[Constant])
            ELSE
            [v].[Percent] * [v].[Constant] 
      END
      AS [RunningTotal]
FROM  [#tmp_Values] v
WHERE [v].[Year] = 2000
UNION ALL
SELECT v2.[Year]
      ,v2.[Percent]
      ,v2.[Constant]
      ,CASE WHEN [v2].[Percent] < 0 THEN
            [v].[RunningTotal] + (([v2].[Percent] + 1) * [v].[RunningTotal])
            ELSE
            [v2].[Percent] * [v].[RunningTotal] 
      END
      AS [RunningTotal]
FROM  values_cte v
    INNER JOIN [#tmp_Values] v2 ON v2.[Year] = v.[Year] + 1    
)
SELECT * 
FROM  [values_cte]
```

Comment: this was what I was originally working towards, and works. However the issue here is when the data set has negative numbers, which I forgot to include earlier. The resulting RunningTotal is incorrect. I tried using a case to check if percep < 0 and > 0, but RunningTotal its not quite correct

Comment: I added a case which should accommodate your negative percentages

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (const * sum(1 + percent / 100) over (order by year)) as rolling_sum
from t
order by t.year;
```

EDIT:

Ooops, I notice you really seem to want a cumulative product.  Assuming `percent` is always greater than 0, then just use logs:

```
select t.*,
       (const * exp(sum(log(1 + percent / 100)) over (order by year))) as rolling_product
from t
order by t.year;
```

Comment: I am going to test a little to see the performance changes as the dataset gets larger. When viewing the execution plan on this tiny dataset for this solution vs a recursive cte, the cte takes 1/2 the time. Do you have any insight into why that would be?

Comment: still not a huge set, but with 1000 records the performance difference remains the same. Your solution, however, doesn't have to account for `MAXRECURSION`.... seems worth the time cost.

Comment: @NateAnderson . . . On larger data sets, I would expect the cumulative sum to far outperform the CTE.  It surprises me that the CTE works so well.

Answer (score 2):

use LEAD keyword

```
SELECT
   Year
,  Percent
,  Constant
,  Percent * Constant * (LEAD(Percent) OVER(ORDER BY Year)) as RunningTotal
FROMYourTable
```

this is new keyword from MSSQL 2012

Comment: Note:  `lead()` is a window/aggregation function.  It isn't a keyword.  The answer is not correct, but the terminology can be.

Comment: hm. I'm sorry My previous answer was incorrect. this will be better:
       Percent * Constant * ISNULL((LAG(Percent) OVER(ORDER BY Year ASC)), 1) as RunningTotal